# Drools- how to find out which all rules were matched?

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine

I've one .DRL file which has say 10 rules. Once I insert a fact, some rules may be matched- how do I find out which rules were matched  programmatically?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

*Note that this answer is valid for versions of Drools up to 5.x. If you have moved on to 6 or above, then take a look at the modified answer from @melchoir55. I haven't tested it myself, but I'll trust that it works.*

To keep track of rule activations, you can use an AgendaEventListener. Below is an example, as found here:

https://github.com/gratiartis/sctrcd-payment-validation-web/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sctrcd/drools/util/TrackingAgendaEventListener.java

You just need to create such a listener and attach it to the session like so:

```
ksession = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
AgendaEventListener agendaEventListener = new TrackingAgendaEventListener();
ksession.addEventListener(agendaEventListener);
//...
ksession.fireAllRules();
//...
List<Activation> activations = agendaEventListener.getActivationList();
```

Note that there is also WorkingMemoryEventListener which enables you to do the same with tracking insertions, updates and retractions of facts.

Code for a tracking & logging AgendaEventListener:

```
package com.sctrcd.drools.util;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.drools.definition.rule.Rule;
import org.drools.event.rule.DefaultAgendaEventListener;
import org.drools.event.rule.AfterActivationFiredEvent;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

/**
 * A listener that will track all rule firings in a session.
 * 
 * @author Stephen Masters
 */
public class TrackingAgendaEventListener extends DefaultAgendaEventListener {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TrackingAgendaEventListener.class);

    private List<Activation> activationList = new ArrayList<Activation>();

    @Override
    public void afterActivationFired(AfterActivationFiredEvent event) {
        Rule rule = event.getActivation().getRule();

        String ruleName = rule.getName();
        Map<String, Object> ruleMetaDataMap = rule.getMetaData();

        activationList.add(new Activation(ruleName));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Rule fired: " + ruleName);

        if (ruleMetaDataMap.size() > 0) {
            sb.append("\n  With [" + ruleMetaDataMap.size() + "] meta-data:");
            for (String key : ruleMetaDataMap.keySet()) {
                sb.append("\n    key=" + key + ", value="
                        + ruleMetaDataMap.get(key));
            }
        }

        log.debug(sb.toString());
    }

    public boolean isRuleFired(String ruleName) {
        for (Activation a : activationList) {
            if (a.getRuleName().equals(ruleName)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void reset() {
        activationList.clear();
    }

    public final List<Activation> getActivationList() {
        return activationList;
    }

    public String activationsToString() {
        if (activationList.size() == 0) {
            return "No activations occurred.";
        } else {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Activations: ");
            for (Activation activation : activationList) {
                sb.append("\n  rule: ").append(activation.getRuleName());
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please update your answer with @melchoir55's answer since it's not working anymore with the actual versions

Answer (score 23):

Steve's answer is solid, but the major changes brought in drools 6 make the code obsolete. I am posting below a rewrite of Steve's code which takes into account the new api:

```
package your.preferred.package;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.drools.core.event.DefaultAgendaEventListener;
import org.kie.api.definition.rule.Rule;
import org.kie.api.event.rule.AfterMatchFiredEvent;
import org.kie.api.runtime.rule.Match;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

/**
 * A listener that will track all rule firings in a session.
 * 
 * @author Stephen Masters, Isaac Martin
 */
public class TrackingAgendaEventListener extends DefaultAgendaEventListener  {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TrackingAgendaEventListener.class);

    private List<Match> matchList = new ArrayList<Match>();

    @Override
    public void afterMatchFired(AfterMatchFiredEvent event) {
        Rule rule = event.getMatch().getRule();

        String ruleName = rule.getName();
        Map<String, Object> ruleMetaDataMap = rule.getMetaData();

        matchList.add(event.getMatch());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Rule fired: " + ruleName);

        if (ruleMetaDataMap.size() > 0) {
            sb.append("\n  With [" + ruleMetaDataMap.size() + "] meta-data:");
            for (String key : ruleMetaDataMap.keySet()) {
                sb.append("\n    key=" + key + ", value="
                        + ruleMetaDataMap.get(key));
            }
        }

        log.debug(sb.toString());
    }

    public boolean isRuleFired(String ruleName) {
        for (Match a : matchList) {
            if (a.getRule().getName().equals(ruleName)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void reset() {
        matchList.clear();
    }

    public final List<Match> getMatchList() {
        return matchList;
    }

    public String matchsToString() {
        if (matchList.size() == 0) {
            return "No matchs occurred.";
        } else {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Matchs: ");
            for (Match match : matchList) {
                sb.append("\n  rule: ").append(match.getRule().getName());
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: it will throw exception:  java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:922) ~[na:1.7.0_60] at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:956) ~[na:1.7.0_60] at org.drools.core.impl.StatelessKnowledgeSessionImpl.registerCustomListeners(StatelessKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:188) ~[drools-core-6.2.0.Final.jar:6.2.0.Final] at org.drools.core.impl.StatelessKnowledgeSessionImpl.newWorkingMemory(StatelessKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:140)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a static logger factory which will log with your favorite logger the actions from your DRL file.

For instance:

```
import org.drools.runtime.rule.RuleContext;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public final class DRLLogger {

private DRLLogger() {
}

protected static Logger getLogger(final RuleContext drools) {
    final String category = drools.getRule().getPackageName() + "." + drools.getRule().getName();
    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(category);
    return logger;
}

public static void info(final RuleContext drools, final String message, final Object... parameters) {
    final Logger logger = getLogger(drools);
    logger.info(message, parameters);
}

public static void debug(final RuleContext drools, final String message, final Object... parameters) {
    final Logger logger = getLogger(drools);
    logger.debug(message, parameters);
}

public static void error(final RuleContext drools, final String message, final Object... parameters) {
    final Logger logger = getLogger(drools);
    logger.error(message, parameters);
}

}
```

Then from your DRL file:

```
import function com.mycompany.DRLLogger.*

rule "myrule"
when
    $fact: Fact()
then
    info(drools, "Fact:{}", $fact);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the dialect to JAVA  in DRL file.

Insert a HashMap from the java file to DRL file (using Drools session concept), 
which should contain the rule name as key and boolean value as result.

Follow this [link](http://drools.46999.n3.nabble.com/How-to-use-hashmap-in-drools-file-td4021479.html) to know how to insert Map to the DRL file.

You can now find which rule exactly matched.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can print info about rule executed from DRL file itself using RuleContext:drools

```
System.out.println(drools.getRule().getName())
```