# Java Drools - which Rules are applied and facts list

Tags: java, drools

I'm a little bit new to drools and i want to understand more of it for a project, so i made a simple program with drools on eclipse.
The workflow is quite simple, i have a model for jwelery products, and for each piece of jwelery i apply one discount based on the name.

That works great, but i want do see the list of the facts and which facts are used for each triggered rule.
I have this:

**Rules.drl**

```
package com.rule

import com.javainuse.model.Product
import com.javainuse.model.Counter

rule "Offer for Diamond"
    when 
        productObject: Product(type=="diamond")
    then
        productObject.setDiscount(15);
    end

rule "Offer for Gold"
    when 
        productObject: Product(type=="gold")
    then
        productObject.setDiscount(25);
    end
```

**model.Product.java**

```
package com.javainuse.model;

public class Product {
    private String type;
    private int discount;

   public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public int getDiscount() {
        return discount;
    }

    public void setDiscount(int discount) {
        this.discount = discount;
    }
}
```

**main.DroolsTest.java**

```
package com.javainuse.main;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.drools.compiler.compiler.DroolsParserException;
import org.drools.compiler.compiler.PackageBuilder;
import org.drools.core.FactHandle;
import org.drools.core.RuleBase;
import org.drools.core.RuleBaseFactory;
import org.drools.core.WorkingMemory;
import com.javainuse.model.Product;

public class DroolsTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws DroolsParserException,
            IOException {
        DroolsTest droolsTest = new DroolsTest();
        droolsTest.executeDrools();
    }

    public void executeDrools() throws DroolsParserException, IOException {

        PackageBuilder packageBuilder = new PackageBuilder();

        String ruleFile = "/com/rule/Rules.drl";
        InputStream resourceAsStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(ruleFile);

        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(resourceAsStream);
        packageBuilder.addPackageFromDrl(reader);
        org.drools.core.rule.Package rulesPackage = packageBuilder.getPackage();
        RuleBase ruleBase = RuleBaseFactory.newRuleBase();
        ruleBase.addPackage(rulesPackage);

        WorkingMemory workingMemory = ruleBase.newStatefulSession();

        Product product = new Product();
        Product product2 = new Product();
        product.setType("gold");
        product2.setType("diamond");

        //List of facts!
        workingMemory.insert(product);
        workingMemory.insert(product2);
        workingMemory.fireAllRules();

System.out.println("Discount for " + product.getType() + " is " + product.getDiscount());

        System.out.println("Discount for " + product2.getType() + " is " + product2.getDiscount());

        //how many facts
        System.out.println("There are " + workingMemory.getFactCount() + " facts");
        //facts handles
        Collection<org.kie.api.runtime.rule.FactHandle> x = workingMemory.getFactHandles();
        System.out.println("Facts Handles: " + x +"\n");

        FactHandle fh;
        Iterator<org.kie.api.runtime.rule.FactHandle> it =  x.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            fh = (FactHandle) it.next();
            System.out.println("FactHandle to string "+fh.toExternalForm().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Discount for gold is 25
Discount for diamond is 15
There are 2 facts
Facts Handles: [[fact 0:2:1889057031:1889057031:2:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:com.javainuse.model.Product@7098b907], [fact 0:1:93199773:93199773:1:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:com.javainuse.model.Product@58e1d9d]]

FactHandle to string 0:2:1889057031:1889057031:2:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT
FactHandle to string 0:1:93199773:93199773:1:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT
```

> I want something like this:

```
Discount for gold is 25
Discount for diamond is 15
There are 2 facts: gold, diamond
gold triggered rule Offer for Gold
diamond triggered Offer for Diamond
```

Is it possible? I've checked the classes of WorkingMemory, Endpoint, FactHandle but nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution just to check which facts are triggered in the facts list when a rule hits.

- Created a function on **model.Product.java** that `return getType();`
- Then on the main program  **main.Droolstest.java**: calls funtions to get facts `getfacts(workingMemory);`

  ```
  public void getfacts( WorkingMemory workingMemory )
  {
  FactHandle fh;
  Collection<org.kie.api.runtime.rule.FactHandle> x = workingMemory.getFactHandles();
  Iterator<org.kie.api.runtime.rule.FactHandle> it =  x.iterator();

  System.out.println("List of facts");
  while(it.hasNext())
  {
      fh = (FactHandle) it.next();

      Object getobj = workingMemory.getObject(fh);
      //System.out.println("GetObject to string: " + ((Object)getobj));

      if (getobj instanceof RuleFact) {
          System.out.println("\nIt's a Fact: ");
          ((RuleFact) getobj).print();
      }
      //System.out.println("FactHandle to string "+ ((Object) fh.toExternalForm()).toString());
     }

  }
  ```

> output:

```
Constructor RuleFact to gold
Constructor RuleFact to diamond
Constructor RuleFact to wood
Inserting facts on the facts list
List of facts

It's a Fact: 
gold

It's a Fact: 
diamond

Fire all the rules
Discount for gold is 95
Discount for diamond is 15
Discount for wood is 0
There are 2 facts
Inserting fact on the facts list
New Rule - fire all the rules
There are 3 facts
Discount for gold is 95
Discount for diamond is 15
Discount for wood is 90
List of facts

It's a Fact: 
wood

It's a Fact: 
gold

It's a Fact: 
diamond
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `AgendaEventListener` to get notified when a rule matches (along with the facts that made it match).

See this post for more details: [Drools- how to find out which all rules were matched?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951880/drools-how-to-find-out-which-all-rules-were-matched/19956086#19956086)

Hope it helps,

Comment: I can't make it work, my version is 6.5 and while trying it, gave me various errors..
is that a way to check it with workingmemory (based on my code..) thanks for your answer!

Comment: There is an answer in that same thread showing ho to make it work on Drools 6. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34539612/1168802

Comment: Can i just list the actual fact list ? i created one abstract class, that product extends, to try to trigger one print that says whichs fact are on the facts list.. but the facts list are on WorkingMemory.. im stuck

Answer (score 0):

There are variety of options to debug drools rules in Eclipse using the Drools plugin (since you told you're using this IDE).

Consider to use `KieRuntimeLogger` to obtain a debug information.

After the `KieSession` instance is obtained it is possible to register a new `KieRuntimeLogger`:

```
KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("ksession-rules");

KieRuntimeLogger kieLogger = ks.getLoggers().newFileLogger(kSession, "log");
```

Run your drools application and check your project folder. There you will find the `log.log` (SIC!) file which contains a list of actions being invoked during the rule execution.

Here is the detailed [article](http://java.msk.ru/debugging-drools-project-using-kieruntimelogger-audit-log/) on this.